# can't get coffeescript-to-typescript to work

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, typescript

I'm migrating a coffeescript app into typescript. There is a [coffeescript-to-typescript](https://github.com/palantir/coffeescript-to-typescript) tool that seems to help a lot with the job. Unfortunately, I can't get it working and the errors thrown seem ridiculous...

This is an example coffee file:

```
CoreModule.service('FileRequire', [
  # dependencies
  () ->
    @resolver = (subdirectory, extension) ->
      (pathcode) ->
        tmp = pathcode.split ':'
        modules = tmp[0]
        file = tmp[1]
        'app/modules/' + modules.split('/').join('/modules/') + '/' + subdirectory + '/' + file + '.' + extension

    return
])
```

And this is how I try to execute it (on Windows machine with `typescript` and `coffeescript-to-typescript` modules installed globally):

```
C:\development\mp-frontend>coffee-to-typescript -cma app\modules\core\services\FileRequire.coffee
error compiling app\modules\core\services\FileRequire.coffee
app\modules\core\services\FileRequire.coffee:4:6: error: unexpected TERMINATOR
    @resolver = (subdirectory, extension) ->
     ^
1 files failed
```

and

```
C:\development\mp-frontend>coffee-to-typescript -c app\modules\core\services\FileRequire.coffee
Error: spawn tsc ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
    at child_process.js:1137:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on? The `TERMINATOR` error seems to be a random error happening with coffeescript, although the application compiles with grunt and works perfetcly fine (it does transpile down to javascript afterall, so the code has to be proper coffee).

The tool seems completely useless so far... please point me on what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Why not compile Coffeescript into JavaScript and then retroactively add typing? It is unlikely you would get typing inferred from any compiler from CoffeeScript and all Javascript is valid Typescript so

Comment: well, I know I can do that. But my question is strict: what am I doing wrong when trying to use this tool.

Comment: I don't know, I've never used that tool. However my point is that the tool is more or less useless as it's going to convert CS -> JS and then into TS on its own in best case scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the same error message as you did. However, it seems that proper installation process for the tool is:

```
sudo npm install -g coffee-script-to-typescript
sudo npm install -g tsc # This is the step that helped me.
```

It works for me on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Have you managed to get it work on Windows? In my case it's not working. Same error.

Comment: I didn't need Windows at that time. We have used this tool in a semi-automatic fashion on Linux as far as I recall.

Answer (score -2):

> The tool seems completely useless so far... please point me on what am I doing wrong

I would recommend just compiling the coffescript to JavaScript, and then start using the JavaScript *as TypeScript* i.e. start adding annotations slowly and migrating to ES6 features like classes.

Comment: Is this an answer to my question, which is how to make `coffeescript-to-typescript` work? Sorry, but I don't find this answer useful anyhow. I know I can do what you wrote.